# Xcode 6.4 highlights just some keywords

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, syntax-highlighting

Since last week, Xcode 6.4 highlights syntax in my Objective-C files in a strange way. Some keywords (nil, id, self, __weak,...) are highlighted but some keywords (int, double, void, if, static, const,...) are not.

I have tried to delete Derived Data of the project but it has not helped. This partial keyword highlighting apply to any project.

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks.

[image: keyword highlighting]

[image]

Comment: At least show a screenshot.

Comment: @SanitLee Screenshot added.

Comment: I mean a screenshot when those you mentioned highlighted.

Comment: @SanitLee Not sure if I understand you. I have added one more screenshot. Keywords `self`, `nil` and `unsigned` are highlighted on the screenshots. Keywords `static`, `const`, `super`, `void`, `if`, `else`, `int` are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have 2 projects for the same application, A v1 and A v2.

This happened to me on v2. I looked at my friends Xcode and he had no problem. I opened v1 and it had no problem. Even some files in v2 had this problem and some of the files didn't have this problem.

I did these steps, not sure which one did the trick but it worked:

- Clean/Build
- cmd + Q/Reopen Xcode
- Clear Derived Data

Comment: Works like a charm. Clearing Derived Data after reopening Xcode was not even necessary. (I forgot the Build step by the way but it worked anyway.) Of course, I tried to clean the project many times and I tried to reopen Xcode many times. However, it seems that quit - reopen must be done immediately after clean.